# Como alinhar campos de um formulário

Tags: html, css

Boas, estou a desenvolver uma webpage com um formulário. Como posso alinhar as caixas de texto para preencher?
Tentei pôr tudo dentro de uma div com a class container, tentei definir o size para tamanhos aproximados, mas há sempre milimetros de diferença, e tentei fazer dentro de uma tabela, mas ficam com espaçamentos pequenos.
Até ao momento o código está assim:

```
<div style="margin-top: 30px;" class="container">
        <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>">

            <h3>Dados Funcionario nº<?php echo $registo["IDFuncionario"]; ?></h3><br>
            <p>Nome <input type="text" name="Nome" size="50" value="<?php echo $registo["Nome"]; ?>"></p>
            <p>Username<input type="text" name="username" size="47" value="<?php echo $registo["username"]; ?>"></p>
            <p>Password<input type="text" name="password" size="47" value="<?php echo $registo["password"]; ?>"></p>
            <p>Morada<input type="text" name="morada" size="49" value="<?php echo $registo["morada"]; ?>"></p>
            <p>Contacto <input type="text" name="contacto" size="47" maxlength="9" value="<?php echo $registo["contacto"]; ?>"></p><br>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Alterar" name="alterar"><input type="reset" value="Repor" name="B2"></p>
        </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Para lhe ajudarmos de forma melhor e mais rápida, inclua o código que tens até o momento.

Comment: Seja bem vindo. Use as tags relevantes a duvida e não ao teu projeto todo amigo.

Comment: Editei por que não deves usar snippet para demonstrar códigos PHP. Use snippet para reproduzir "problemas" com CSS, html, js e só.

Answer (score 4):

Dá pra fazer com CSS utilizando a tag `<label>`, assim:

```css
label.hora {

    display: inline-block;
    width: 90px;
}
```

```html
<label for="input1" class="hora">Entrada 1:</label>
<input type="time" id="input1"><br>

<label for="input2" class="hora">Entrada 22:</label>
<input type="time" id="input2">
```

Coloquei seu código da mesma forma, mas acho que vc não precisa colocar (ou pode estar colocando errado) a abertura do php dentro dos campos `input`... Dei uma editada no seu código, tirando as aberturas do php apenas pra testar, dá uma olhada como ficou (clicando abaixo, em executar trecho de código):

```css
label.hora {

    display: inline-block;
    width: 90px;
}
```

```html
   <div style="margin-top: 30px;" class="container">
<form method="POST" action="">

<h3>Dados Funcionario nº</h3><br>
<label class="hora">Nome </label><input type="text" name="Nome" size="50"><br>
<label class="hora">Username</label><input type="text" name="username" size="47"><br>
<label class="hora">Password</label><input type="text" name="password" size="47"><br>
<label class="hora">Morada</label><input type="text" name="morada" size="49"><br>
<label class="hora">Contacto</label><input type="text" name="contacto" size="47" maxlength="9"><br>
<p><input type="submit" value="Alterar" name="alterar"><input type="reset" value="Repor" name="B2"></p>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: `display: inline-block;` não é CSS3

Comment: Ok, valeu pelo esclarecimento e pela edição! PS: Eu aumentei um "2" no segundo horário pra mostrar que o alinhamento funciona mesmo com palavras de tamanho diferente....